# How do I make this curl call with nodejs request module

Tags: node.js, curl, httprequest, put

I am able to send a request to browsermob using curl like so:
`curl -X PUT -d "pageRef=car" localhost:9000/proxy/8081/har/pageRef`. However, I would like to do this inside nodejs using the request module. What is the equivalent command using the request module? I assume it is something like `request.put(url, data, callback)` but when I try `request.put('localhost:9000/proxy/8081/har/pageRef', {form: { pageRef: encodeURI(browser.platform) + encodeURI(browser.browserName) + encodeURI(browser.version) }})`, I get

`Error: Invalid protocol
    at Request.self._buildRequest (/Users/dragonite/Pixel/node_modules/request/request.js:336:53)
    at Request.init (/Users/dragonite/Pixel/node_modules/request/request.js:503:10)
    at new Request (/Users/dragonite/Pixel/node_modules/request/request.js:97:8)
    at request (/Users/dragonite/Pixel/node_modules/request/index.js:50:11)
    at Function.request.put (/Users/dragonite/Pixel/node_modules/request/index.js:121:27)
    at repl:1:10
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:203:10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are just missing the protocol in front of the url like:

```
request.put('http://localhost:9000/proxy/8081/har/pageRef', {form: { pageRef: encodeURI(browser.platform) + encodeURI(browser.browserName) + encodeURI(browser.version) }})
```